# Clearing the cell after pressing enter in certain column only

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and currently trying to figure out how to clear cells from a certain column after pressing enter. I found this code from another question:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This works fine except it does it for all cells on the worksheet. I know that the code to select a column is

```
Columns(3).Select
```

(3 is the column I want on this occasion). I tried putting it like this

```
Target.ClearContents = Columns(3).Select
```

This then made it so that if I enter data in a different column it causes an error so I tried this to get around it

```
If Columns(3).Select = "" Then
Else
    Target.ClearContents = Columns(3).Select
End If
```

This came with runtime error 424 object required and nothing I've done since this seems to get me anywhere.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user modifies more than one cell at a time, in column 3 and possibly other Columns too

Comment: The other columns don't matter, they don't need to be cleared it's only in column 3. The reason I need it cleared is beacuse Im using an iterative calculation (I know people say to avoid these but there's no other option) and if it's not cleared then each time the user edits any other cell the calculation will run again messing up the data. So the user will be inputting into say C5, pressing enter, calculation will do its thing then the cell will be cleared, theyll then do the same in C6 C7 C8 etc. I believe this answers your question but i may have misunerstood.

Comment: Users can do all sorts of unexpected things, including pasting a block of data into several cells at once, which may include Column C and/or other columns.  Your code should be robust enough to handle it.  I'm encouraging Xabier to update their answer, so watch this space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for, but this does not look to see if the user pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> on the given cell, it simply looks to see if any changes have been made on the cell, this includes selecting the cell as if to make some changes but then moving to another cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**
To check if the user pasted data for example on `C3:E4` then the following will make sure that only data on Column C is removed, thanks to Chris Neilsen for his comment:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range, Arr As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each Arr In Target.Areas
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Columns(3), Arr)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.ClearContents
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What if user pasted data to say`C3:E4`?  This would clear cells in columns `D` and `E` as well.

Comment: @chrisneilsen yes it would as the target would change to the pasted range. I've updated my answer to reflect your comment. :)

Comment: Sorry, but that won't do it - that would clear  `E3:E4` if `C3:E4` changed.  Try using `Intersect`

Comment: @chrisneilsen not sure how I would use Intersect to remove only data from Column C, I tested my updated code on Column 1 and it seemed to work, obviously it doesn't work when pasting into C3:E4, any pointers? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm posting on my phone, so will give you an outline and leave it to you to test.  `Dim rng as Range, Arr as Range  For Each Arr in Target.Areas  Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Columns(3), Arr)  If Not rng is Nothing Then  rng.ClearContents  End If  Next`